# How to save text file which has been modified through a Master Details Block in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, master-detail

I created a multi page editor with a text editor page and a Master Details Block page. In the Master Details block I have a list with entries which have been parsed from a text file.

These text files have the following structure:

```
myVar = 23423423;
SEARCH(myVar)
block
   {
       text = test;
   }
```

When I click on one of the entries, for example `myVar`, a detail block with two forms will be displayed, one input field for the variable name and one for the corresponding value. If I change the entries through this form, the respective object will be modified. However, it will not mark the multi page editor as dirty and it will not ask me if I want to save my changes. greg-449 [told me today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34607324/5594380), that I need to save the file manually, so I tried the following:

```
public class MyParser {

    private MyModel model;
    private long lastModified;
    private IFile file;

    public MyParser(FileEditorInput input) {
        this.file = input.getFile();
        this.lastModified = input.getFile().getModificationStamp();
        parse();
    }

    private void parse() {
        try {
            InputStream in = file.getContents();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            List<MyField> variables = new ArrayList<MyField>();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splittedLine = line.split("=");
                if (splittedLine.length >= 2)
                    variables
                            .add(new MyVariable(splittedLine[0], splittedLine[1]));
                   // Implement other entry types
            }
            System.out.println(out.toString()); // Prints the string content
                                                // read from input stream
            reader.close();
            this.setModel(new MyModel().add(variables, false));

        } catch (CoreException | IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    public void saveChanges() {
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file.getLocation().toFile());
            try {
                saveChanges(writer);
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    file.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE,
                            new NullProgressMonitor());
                } catch (CoreException e) {

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    public void saveChanges(Writer writer) {
        //TODO
        this.getModel().setDirty(false);
    }

    public long getLastModified() {
        return this.lastModified;
    }

    public MyModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(MyModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
```

How can I save the modified objects to the original file? Do I need to overwrite the file completely or is it possible to change only the dirty values? Furthermore, the order of the entries in the text files is important. Do I need to remember the line numbers, because this may be a problem when adding new entries somewhere in the middle of the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the entire contents of the file. Use the `IFile.setContents` method to set the contents of an existing file. It is up to you to get the order of the contents correct.

For a `FormEditor` call `editorDirtyStateChanged()` to tell the editor that the 'dirty' state has changed. Each `IFormPage` should implement `isDirty` as appropriate (or override the `FormEditor` `isDirty` method).

If the dirty state is correct a '*' is added to the editor title. A 'do you want' to save dialog will also be displayed on exit if the editor is dirty.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How do I tell eclipse, as soon as users modify the field, that the file can be saved (usually there is an asterisk besides the tab)? Furthermore, if users have modified the entries and close the editor, a popup should open, how can I do this?

Comment: Added dirty state details.